# Прозрачный текст без размытия на filter: blur() родителе

Tags: вёрстка

Где-то на бихансе нашел вот такой чудной экран, из интереса попытался повторить самый сочный кусок но уперся в проблему того что свойство backdrop-filter будет передаваться и тексту, есть идеи как добиться результата со скрина?

Ссылка на мой вариант (закомментил backdrop-filter) - [codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/BaVoryJ)

[image: transparent text]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: sans-serif;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666344869474-15bd512549e5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box {
    height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 2rem;
    // backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    color: black;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    background-clip: text;
}

h1 {
    padding-right: 4rem;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>COL</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Псевдоэлемент с z-index: -1 надо использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy а можно пример? с z-index у меня не сработало...